# Is there a way to make Chrome display the SVG cursor as it is in Safari?

Tags: css, svg, cross-browser, compatibility

I am using an SVG file as the mouse pointer in CSS. Safari displays it correctly where Chrome displays black dots around it, like poorly made transparent GIF artifacts.

Check the fiddle in Safari and Chrome respectively, you will see what I mean.

```
.element {
   ... 
   cursor: url(http://wiki.ooo4kids.org/images/b/b3/Cursor-Hand.svg), e-resize;
   ...
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cdolek/nx6st28k/7/

Is there a way to make them look the same?

[image: Gif animation]

Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.5 (14F1021)

- Left: Chrome Version 46.0.2490.86 (64-bit)
- Right: Safari Version
  9.0.1 (10601.2.7.2)

GIF url: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1324709/screencap.gif

Comment: I can't see a difference between them -> https://www.dropbox.com/s/ypjxnr6i3tt4avn/mouse.gif?dl=0 (osx: 10.11.1, safari 9.0.1 (11601.2.7.2), chrome 47.0.2526.58)

Comment: hmm. I am seeing this -> https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1324709/screencap.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug inside chrome 46

Chrome 45:
[image: Chrome 45]

Chrome 46:
[image]

Chrome 47:
[image]

Comment: I'm using Chrome beta ;)